# Name of dispatcher servlet xml in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

There are many Qs and As on this matter but I have not seen an answer to why my project works. I started it out following a tutorial so it just worked. This is the declaration of my Spring Dispatcher Servlet in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then I have my servlet definition in a file in the same folder called `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. But I am not declaring in the web.xml that the definition is to be found in that particular file. How can the web app know that this is the correct file?

I have seen other default names of the file in answers but none like mine. Is `dispatcher-servlet.xml` a default name that Spring knows about and can find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Spring MVC documentation:

> Upon initialization of a DispatcherServlet, Spring MVC looks for a
>   file named [servlet-name]-servlet.xml in the WEB-INF directory of your
>   web application and creates the beans defined there, overriding the
>   definitions of any beans defined with the same name in the global
>   scope.

Since your servlet name is 'dispatcher' Spring looks for the file dispatcher-servlet.xml in the default location of your WEB-INF folder.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html